# Is it possible to tell browser not to POST again (w/o redirect)?

Tags: browser, redirect

If F5 is pressed after a POST request has been issued, browser will ask, whether the user wants to resubmit the post data. However, if redirect follows the POST request, no dialog appears. Is it possible to disable that dialog for a single page without redirecting the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is built in behavior of the browser and can't be overridden.

Redirecting after the post is the easiest option to avoid the effects of reposting, there are other options to avoid issues with reposting but if it is to the same URL, you will still get the browser dialog.

Comment: Correct. You must use Post-Redirect-Get if you don't want to prompt the user.